# How to disable Kerberos authentication for Outlook on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, exchange, kerberos

**A bit of background:** I'm trying to debug an issue with Outlook taking a long time (20s) to connect to Exchange 2013 when being on the same network as Exchange (connected with Ethernet cable) but connecting considerably faster (100ms) when VPNing to that same network (over WiFi, or any outside connection).

While debugging with Wireshark and Burp Suite, I found that even merely forcing Outlook to proxy via a local Burp instance also made the connection as fast as over VPN. After trying many things and failing, I want to exclude Kerberos issues since Kerberos I've heard from multiple people that it doesn't play well with Exchange's AutoDiscover.

**So my question is:** How can I disable Kerberos authentication for Outlook on my own Windows 7 machine? I've already played with the `NT4Emulator` and `LmCompatibilityLevel` keys, but no success.

Comment: What version of Exchange, what protocol are you using?

Comment: @doenoe It's Exchange 2013. I'm not really sure what protocol, but I believe it's the default Exchange stuff. I'm more interested in adjusting this on my own machine rather than corp network and servers.

Comment: And you are sure the client is connecting with kerberos authentication? I dont think you can adjust Exchange authentication methods on the clients side.